# How to change Android 2.3 Options menu item More text

Tags: android

How can i change the text of the Options menu item 'More' ? i want to change translate this to another language. I am running Android 2.2

Thanks

Comment: It should already be in the device's language, as determined in Settings. Is that not working for you?